# Center text over multicolumn in table

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, formatting, multicolumn

I have created a table that is the width of my page, but when trying to center the text in the top row over the merged cell, the text is not centering with respect to the entire length of the cell.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{N}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{.5in}}
\newcolumntype{G}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{2in}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{N|N|N|N|N|N|N|N|N|}
\cline{2-9}
\multicolumn{1}{N|}{\textbf{}} & \multicolumn{4}{G|}{\textbf{Emissions (Pre Catalytic Converter)}} & \multicolumn{4}{G|}{\textbf{Emissions (Post Catalytic Converter)}} \\  \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|N|}{\textbf{Dyno Load (\%)}} & \textbf{CO (\%)} & \textbf{HC (ppm)} & \textbf{Nox (ppm)} & \textbf{$\boldsymbol{\mathrm{CO_2}}$ (\%)} & \textbf{CO (\%)} & \textbf{HC (ppm)} & \textbf{Nox (ppm)} & \textbf{$\boldsymbol{\mathrm{CO_2}}$ (\%)} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|N|}{10} & 0.77 & 23 & 523 & 14.0 & 0.09 & 18 & 130 & 13.8 \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{30} & 0.78 & 13 & 555 & 14.2 & - & - & - & - \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{70} & 0.70 & 14 & 580 & 14.4 & - & - & - & - \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{90} & 0.74 & 15 & 630 & 14.5 & 0.70 & 15 & 618 & 14.6 \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Neutral} & 0.06 & 7 & 21 & 15.6 & 0.06 & 5 & 27 & 15.7 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{\textbf{}}
\label{2000Emissions}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! There is `\usepackage{amsbsy}` missing. And from some aesthetically point of view: Too much lines

Comment: You want to combine 4 cells, each of them has 2 `\tabcolsep` space left and right of the cell content, so it's 6\tabcolsep in addition, I suppose

Answer (score 12):

In this case it is easier to just use two lines for the titles:

[image]

### Notes:

- You don't need to use `\multicolumn{1}{N|}{\textbf{}}`, just leaving it blank is sufficient.

---

However, I think you table would lok much better if you eliminated the vertical rules and used the `booktabs` package:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{N}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{.5in}}
\newcolumntype{G}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{2in}}

\newcommand*{\boldsymbol}[1]{#1}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{N|N|N|N|N|N|N|N|N|}
\cline{2-9}
     & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{\textbf{Emissions (Pre}} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{\textbf{Emissions (Post}} \\  
     & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{\textbf{Catalytic Converter)}} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{\textbf{Catalytic Converter)}} \\  \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|N|}{\textbf{Dyno Load (\%)}} & \textbf{CO (\%)} & \textbf{HC (ppm)} & \textbf{Nox (ppm)} & \textbf{$\boldsymbol{\mathrm{CO_2}}$ (\%)} & \textbf{CO (\%)} & \textbf{HC (ppm)} & \textbf{Nox (ppm)} & \textbf{$\boldsymbol{\mathrm{CO_2}}$ (\%)} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|N|}{10} & 0.77 & 23 & 523 & 14.0 & 0.09 & 18 & 130 & 13.8 \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{30} & 0.78 & 13 & 555 & 14.2 & - & - & - & - \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{70} & 0.70 & 14 & 580 & 14.4 & - & - & - & - \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{90} & 0.74 & 15 & 630 & 14.5 & 0.70 & 15 & 618 & 14.6 \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Neutral} & 0.06 & 7 & 21 & 15.6 & 0.06 & 5 & 27 & 15.7 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{\textbf{}}
\label{2000Emissions}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

### Code: `booktabs`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\newcolumntype{N}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{.5in}}
\newcolumntype{G}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{2in}}

\newcommand*{\boldsymbol}[1]{#1}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\noindent
\begin{tabular}{N N N N N N N N N }\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{N }{\textbf{}} & \multicolumn{4}{c }{\textbf{Emissions (Pre}} & \multicolumn{4}{c }{\textbf{Emissions (Post}} \\  
\multicolumn{1}{c }{\textbf{}} & \multicolumn{4}{c }{\textbf{Catalytic Converter)}} & \multicolumn{4}{c }{\textbf{Catalytic Converter)}} \\ 
\cmidrule(lr){2-5}
\cmidrule(ll){6-9}
\multicolumn{1}{ N }{\textbf{Dyno Load (\%)}} & \textbf{CO (\%)} & \textbf{HC (ppm)} & \textbf{Nox (ppm)} & \textbf{$\boldsymbol{\mathrm{CO_2}}$ (\%)} & \textbf{CO (\%)} & \textbf{HC (ppm)} & \textbf{Nox (ppm)} & \textbf{$\boldsymbol{\mathrm{CO_2}}$ (\%)} \\ 
\cmidrule(lr){1-1}
\cmidrule(lr){2-5}
\cmidrule(ll){6-9}
\multicolumn{1}{ N }{10} & 0.77 & 23 & 523 & 14.0 & 0.09 & 18 & 130 & 13.8 \\ 
\multicolumn{1}{ c }{30} & 0.78 & 13 & 555 & 14.2 & - & - & - & - \\ 
\multicolumn{1}{ c }{70} & 0.70 & 14 & 580 & 14.4 & - & - & - & - \\ 
\multicolumn{1}{ c }{90} & 0.74 & 15 & 630 & 14.5 & 0.70 & 15 & 618 & 14.6 \\ 
\multicolumn{1}{ c }{Neutral} & 0.06 & 7 & 21 & 15.6 & 0.06 & 5 & 27 & 15.7 \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{\textbf{}}
\label{2000Emissions}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: add a `\toprule` and the 2nd table will be just perfect! :)

Comment: @tohecz: Good suggestion. Have added a `\toprule`.

Answer (score 4):

I used the code and 'improved' it a little bit.

There are 4 cells to be merged, meaning, this is not just 4 times the cell content width of the 'N' type.

|scs|scs|scs|scs|

Where `s` means `\tabcolsep` space (defaulting to `6pt` and `c` the cell content, 'fixed' to `0.5in`

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsbsy}%
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{calc}
\newcolumntype{N}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{.5in}}
\newcolumntype{G}{>{\bfseries\centering\arraybackslash}m{2in+6\tabcolsep}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{*{9}{N|}}
\cline{2-9}
\multicolumn{1}{N|}{} & \multicolumn{4}{G|}{Emissions (Pre Catalytic Converter)} & \multicolumn{4}{G|}{Emissions (Post Catalytic Converter)} \tabularnewline  \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|N|}{\textbf{Dyno Load (\%)}} & \textbf{CO (\%)} & \textbf{HC (ppm)} & \textbf{Nox (ppm)} & \textbf{$\boldsymbol{\mathrm{CO_2}}$ (\%)} & \textbf{CO (\%)} & \textbf{HC (ppm)} & \textbf{Nox (ppm)} & \textbf{$\boldsymbol{\mathrm{CO_2}}$ (\%)} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|N|}{10} & 0.77 & 23 & 523 & 14.0 & 0.09 & 18 & 130 & 13.8 \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{30} & 0.78 & 13 & 555 & 14.2 & - & - & - & - \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{70} & 0.70 & 14 & 580 & 14.4 & - & - & - & - \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{90} & 0.74 & 15 & 630 & 14.5 & 0.70 & 15 & 618 & 14.6 \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Neutral} & 0.06 & 7 & 21 & 15.6 & 0.06 & 5 & 27 & 15.7 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{\textbf{}}
\label{2000Emissions}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The lines are naughty ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Numeric tables usually are better typeset using `siunitx`. I prefer the rules provided by `booktabs`, but they aren't necessary: you can use vertical rules, if you prefer having a typographically disputable result. `;-)`

```
\documentclass[draft,a4paper,twoside,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs}

\newcommand{\splitcell}[1]{%
  \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}\strut#1\strut\end{tabular}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{
  S[table-format=2.0]
  S[table-format=1.2]
  S[table-format=2.0]
  S[table-format=3.0]
  S[table-format=2.1]
  S[table-format=1.2]
  S[table-format=2.0]
  S[table-format=3.0]
  S[table-format=2.1]
}
\toprule
 & \multicolumn{8}{c}{\bfseries Emissions} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-9}
 & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\bfseries Pre Catalytic Converter}
 & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\bfseries Post Catalytic Converter} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-5}\cmidrule(lr){6-9}
{\bfseries\splitcell{Dyno\\ Load\\ (\%)}}
 & {\bfseries\splitcell{CO \\ (\%)}}
 & {\bfseries\splitcell{HC \\ (ppm)}}
 & {\bfseries\splitcell{Nox \\ (ppm)}}
 & {\bfseries\boldmath\splitcell{CO$_2$ \\ (\%)}}
 & {\bfseries\splitcell{CO \\ (\%)}}
 & {\bfseries\splitcell{HC \\ (ppm)}}
 & {\bfseries\splitcell{Nox \\ (ppm)}}
 & {\bfseries\boldmath\splitcell{CO$_2$ \\ (\%)}} \\
\midrule
10        & 0.77 & 23 & 523 & 14.0 & 0.09 & 18   & 130  & 13.8 \\
30        & 0.78 & 13 & 555 & 14.2 & {--} & {--} & {--} & {--} \\
70        & 0.70 & 14 & 580 & 14.4 & {--} & {--} & {--} & {--} \\
90        & 0.74 & 15 & 630 & 14.5 & 0.70 & 15   & 618  & 14.6 \\
{Neutral} & 0.06 &  7 &  21 & 15.6 & 0.06 &  5   &  27  & 15.7 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{Some caption}
\label{2000Emissions}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

While each column in `N` has been specified to have width `0.5in`, four `N`-columns is not `2in` wide. Each column is separated by an inter-column space/gap of `\tabcolsep`. And, when you use a vertical rule, it's actually `2\tabcolsep`. As such, you can use a width of `2in+6\tabcolsep` as the space for your `G`-column:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,array,bm,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{N}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{.5in}}
\newcolumntype{G}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{\dimexpr2in+6\tabcolsep}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{N*{8}{|N|}}
  \cline{2-9}
  \multicolumn{1}{N|}{} & \multicolumn{4}{G|}{\bfseries Emissions (Pre Catalytic Converter)} & \multicolumn{4}{G|}{\bfseries Emissions (Post Catalytic Converter)} \\  \hline
  \multicolumn{1}{|N|}{\textbf{Dyno Load (\%)}} & \textbf{CO (\%)} & \textbf{HC (ppm)} & \textbf{Nox (ppm)} & \textbf{$\boldsymbol{\mathrm{CO_2}}$ (\%)} & \textbf{CO (\%)} & \textbf{HC (ppm)} & \textbf{Nox (ppm)} & \textbf{$\boldsymbol{\mathrm{CO_2}}$ (\%)} \\ \hline
  \multicolumn{1}{|N|}{10} & 0.77 & 23 & 523 & 14.0 & 0.09 & 18 & 130 & 13.8 \\ \hline
  \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{30} & 0.78 & 13 & 555 & 14.2 & - & - & - & - \\ \hline
  \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{70} & 0.70 & 14 & 580 & 14.4 & - & - & - & - \\ \hline
  \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{90} & 0.74 & 15 & 630 & 14.5 & 0.70 & 15 & 618 & 14.6 \\ \hline
  \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Neutral} & 0.06 & 7 & 21 & 15.6 & 0.06 & 5 & 27 & 15.7 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{c*{8}{N}}
  \toprule
  & \multicolumn{4}{G}{\bfseries Emissions (Pre Catalytic Converter)} & \multicolumn{4}{G}{\bfseries Emissions (Post Catalytic Converter)} \\
  \cmidrule(lr){2-5}\cmidrule(lr){6-9}
  \multicolumn{1}{N}{\textbf{Dyno Load (\%)}} & \textbf{CO (\%)} & \textbf{HC (ppm)} & \textbf{Nox (ppm)} & \textbf{$\boldsymbol{\mathrm{CO_2}}$ (\%)} & 
    \textbf{CO (\%)} & \textbf{HC (ppm)} & \textbf{Nox (ppm)} & \textbf{$\boldsymbol{\mathrm{CO_2}}$ (\%)} \\
  \midrule
    10    & 0.77 & 23 & 523 & 14.0 & 0.09 & 18 & 130 & 13.8 \\
    30    & 0.78 & 13 & 555 & 14.2 &   -- & -- &  -- &   -- \\
    70    & 0.70 & 14 & 580 & 14.4 &   -- & -- &  -- &   -- \\
    90    & 0.74 & 15 & 630 & 14.5 & 0.70 & 15 & 618 & 14.6 \\
  Neutral & 0.06 &  7 &  21 & 15.6 & 0.06 &  5 &  27 & 15.7 \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

I would use [`booktabs`](http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) though...

Comment: This covers about the same as [Chris' answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/210235/5764), except for the addition of [`booktabs`](http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs).

Comment: I was only 1 minute faster ;-)